How to update a property of an Excel UserForm Control with vba
Here is a sample of code I am trying.
Public Sub AlignHdiTbxs()
    Dim frm As ufViewCourse
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim iWidth As Long
    Dim iHeight As Long
    Dim iLeft As Long
    Dim iTop As Long
    Set frm = New ufViewCourse
    
    For i = 0 To frm.Controls.Count - 1
        Set ctl = frm.Controls(i)
        If Left(ctl.Name, 6) = "tbxHdi" Then
            Debug.Print ctl.Name, ctl.Height, ctl.Left, ctl.Top, ctl.Width
            If Len(ctl.Name) = 7 Then
                iLeft = frm.Controls("tbxPar" & Right(ctl.Name, 1)).Left
                ctl.Left = iLeft
            End If
            If Len(ctl.Name) = 8 Then
                iLeft = frm.Controls("tbxPar" & Right(ctl.Name, 2)).Left
                ctl.Left = iLeft
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub

The above code addresses the UserForm and its controls. The dimensions of the control print out correctly, but the change does not occur. This particular rendition is trying to update the Left property of all of the text boxes whose names start with tbxHdi. There are 18 if them on the form. The code tries to align tbxHdin (n is an integer from 1 to 18) to match a text box named tbxParn (same integer). That is the purpose of all the code from if(Left... to the last end if before Next i. There are no errors, but no changes are made to the controls.
I have tried: ufViewcourse.COntrols("tbxParTotal").height = 15 in the immediate window of the debugger and the same thing happens: No Error, no change.
Any ideas?
Thanks

From where are you calling AlignHdiTbxs?

Set frm = New ufViewCourse - are you not doing anything with frm after this?

The main issue here is that your AlignHdiTbxs method is creating a NEW UserForm on which you are repositioning the controls.  This UserForm is never being shown.  The solution is to use Me.Controls instead of frm.Controls.  This will modify the controls on the active UserForm.  The code below illustrates this idea.  I also took the liberty of simplifying the code:
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
   AlignHdiTbxs
End Sub

Public Sub AlignHdiTbxs()
    Dim ctl As Control
    
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
       If Left(ctl.Name, 6) = "tbxHdi" Then
          ctl.Left = Me.Controls(Replace(ctl.Name, "Hdi", "Par")).Left
       End If
    Next
End Sub

You don't say where you are calling AlignHdiTbxs but this answer should be of some use to you.
